# Library folder missing from backup

Tags: windows-7, backup

I've found an issue with Windows Backup which puzzles me a bit.

I've 3 folders in my Pictures library. One folder (E:\Pictures) is on a secondary hard drive. I've added the library to the backup (which is made on a network drive). However, when I use 'Restore' and browse for the files this folder is missing in the backup? Am I doing something wrong?

Library configuration: 
[image]

Folders in backup
[image]